# How to handle Android Java objects which "extends Activity"?

Tags: android, object, android-activity, lifecycle

Let's say I have two classes:

Class **Show** is my normal Android activity.

Class **Work** is a Java class which does a lot of work:

```
public class Work extends Activity {...}
```

As you can see, **Work** extends Activity. Thats because it needs some methods that are only in Activity (I don't mean methods which regard the UI).

In my Activity **Show** I make an Objekt of class **Work**

```
protected void onCreate(){
      Work mWork = new Work();
      mWork.doSomething();
}
```

My question:
How shall I handle my object **Work** regarding its lifecycle? Is it like a normal Java object and I don't have to care about its lifecycle, or is it like a normal activity and i have to call finish()? I am confused because it's kind of both.

Comment: "it needs some methods that are only in Activity"
Why don't you just make it a normal class that doesn't extend activity, put whatever work you wanna do in some method that takes the same arguments, and call that method from the corresponding overridden method in your Show activity?

Comment: Definitely a good idea to avoid this problem, but it does not really fit my needs. With the Work class I want to work as independent as possible.

Comment: Okay now this question really interests me. Creating a new instance of a class that extends activity, without a new Intent. I'd be interested in knowing more too.

Comment: For example: When I want to write a complex class which only cares about GPS-Locations, I cannot get a LocationManager without extending my class of Activity. Or I just don't know how.

Comment: Oh that. That you can just pass the Activity context to your "complex class" and access the things through that context object, seeing as how Activity is just a class that extends ApplicationContext.
WRT your location example, I'd pass the context from my activity to the other class, and call `myLocationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);` and then proceed.

Comment: That will do. In this case I wouldn't need to care about clearing the object, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on our discussion in the comments, the answer here would be to pass the Context of your current activity to the target class, and use the accessible methods through that context instance to do whatever task it is you want, as the Activity class basically extends ApplicationContext.

For example (in a class not extending Activity) I can add:

```
myLocationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
```

and use `myLocationManager` as I please. Also, this way the object created locally would be set for garbage collection upon destruction of your main Activity.

Thought it'd be worth having an answer others could refer to rather than scrounging through the comments.

Answer (score 1):

you should read [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) to understand activity lifecycle.